# TFS in VS2013, *.dll.add files

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs

I'm using Vs2013, with TFS...
I'm getting a ton of *.dll.add files and some other .add files.

Currently I'm excluding them from checkin...
]
Can you please tell me what they are and what they indicate?

I assume they are some kind of TFS sentinel file...

Comment: What do these DLL's look like, what folder do they appear in? TFS doesn't usually store any of it's own files in your repository.

Comment: It appears to be in folders where I add external Dlls that I need to have references to, But references to dlls built in this project.

Comment: Seems to get added to other extensions too, like exe, and csproj.vspscc. I'm guessing it has something to do with adding the files to TFS...?

Comment: vspscc files should be under source control in TFS. Sometimes adding .exe's to a solution gets TFS confused, but I've never seen that. The DLL's, are they in the packages folder for NuGet?

Comment: Nope, they are files that don't have nugget packages... (we have those too, but they don't seem to have .add files). Some of our external dependencies aren't packaged up yet.